# Не обновляются данные на форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Я делаю игру на WinForms, в которой есть параметр **Сытость**. Он отображается на главной форме (верхняя на скриншоте) и на дочерней (нижняя).

В дочерней форме я могу увеличивать **Сытость** нажатием на соответствующие кнопки.

Проблема в том, что в дочерней форме значение обновляется сразу после нажатия на кнопку, а в главной - только после закрытия дочерней формы. А я хочу сделать, чтобы и там и там сразу значение обновлялось.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вот код главной формы. Он открывает дочернюю форму при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку (например, "Купить еду"), а затем после закрытия формы вызывает метод **MyInitializeComponent**, который обновляет все данные на главной форме (прогрессбары, лейблы и т.п.). Т.е. после закрытия дочерней формы все обновляется нормально.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Food food = new Food();

    // Update progress bar on the main form after closing child form
    food.FormClosed += (s, args) => MyInitializeComponent();
    food.ShowDialog();
    UpdateMoney();
}
```

Ниже код дочерней формы. Вызываю тот же метод после нажатия на кнопку, но на главной форме все еще значение не обновляется **сразу** после нажатия:

```
private static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

private void BuyFood() // Метод вызывается при нажатии на кнопку
{
    mainForm.MyInitializeComponent();
}
```

Метод **MyInitializeComponent** главной формы. **indicators** - это экземпляр класса, в котором хранятся все переменные.

```
    public void MyInitializeComponent()
    {
        label6.Text = indicators.Money + "$";
        label7.Text = indicators.income + "$/д";
        label8.Text = indicators.cost + "$/д";
        label19.Text = indicators.salary + "$/д";
        button8.Text = "Почта (" + indicators.mail + ")";

        label33.Text = indicators.Food + "%";
        progressBar1.Value = indicators.Food;

        label34.Text = indicators.Mood + "%";
        progressBar2.Value = indicators.Mood;

        label16.Text = indicators.currentDay + " " +
                       indicators.currentMonth + ", " +
                       indicators.currentDayOfWeek;
        trackBar1.Value = indicators.gameSpeed;

        label35.Text = indicators.gameCreationProgress + "%";
        progressBar3.Value = indicators.gameCreationProgress;

        label32.Text = indicators.currentGameName;
        label22.Text = indicators.currentGameTimeDone + " (из " +
                       indicators.currentGameTimeAll + ")";
        label24.Text = indicators.gameCreationSpeed + "%";
        label26.Text = indicators.currentGameProfit + "$ + " +
                       indicators.currentGameProfitPerDay + "$/д";

        label11.Text = "Программирование (" +
                       indicators.SkillsProgramming + ")";
        progressBar4.Value = indicators.SkillsProgramming;

        label12.Text = "Руководитель проекта (" +
                       indicators.SkillsTeamLeader + ")";
        progressBar5.Value = indicators.SkillsTeamLeader;

        label13.Text = "Маркетинг (" +
                       indicators.SkillsMarketing + ")";
        progressBar6.Value = indicators.SkillsMarketing;

        label17.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что экземпляр `MainForm` в `Food` форме не имеет никакого отношения к вашей настоящей главной форме. Вам нужно передавать ссылку на `MainForm` в дочернюю при создании. В главной форме:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Food food = new Food(this);

    // Update progress bar on the main form after closing child form
    food.FormClosed += (s, args) => MyInitializeComponent();
    food.ShowDialog();
    UpdateMoney();
}
```

В дочерней:

```
public class Food : Form
{
    private MainForm mainForm;

    public Food(MainForm main)
    {
        mainForm = main;
    }

    private void BuyFood() // Метод вызывается при нажатии на кнопку
    {
        mainForm.MyInitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все получилось